# JavaScript: How to recreate "Animate Your Name" lesson from Codecademy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, html5-canvas

The Codecademy website has a lesson where the user can [learn to **create an animated name** on a canvas element using JavaScript](http://www.codecademy.com/goals/animate-your-name). I've been trying to recreate the result for months, but nothing I've tried has gotten me anywhere close to what I'm looking for.

---

Below is the HTML and JavaScript used in the lesson (Link here: http://www.codecademy.com/goals/animate-your-name). This works, albeit *only* at the Codecademy website.

### JavaScript:

**Note 1**: this version of the JS is *slightly* modified from the original.

**Note 2**: the filename for this JavaScript is **`main.js`**.

```
var red = [359, 100, 29.8];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var bluefield = [199, 100, 22.9];

var myName = "Bluefield";
var letterColors = [bluefield,red];
var bubbleShape = "square";

drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceName();
bounceBubbles();
```

### HTML (full):

**Note**: I had *not* seen this HTML until today (August 6, 2014).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Below is from a **recent JSFiddle using similar code** (Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/cd7djy02/). This *doesn't* work.

### JavaScript

```
var red = [359, 100, 29.8];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var bluefield = [199, 100, 22.9];

var myName = "Bluefield";
var letterColors = [bluefield,red];
var bubbleShape = "square";

drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceName();
bounceBubbles();
```

### HTML (within 'body' tags):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

### External Resources linked (Important!):

- http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js (from HTML of original lesson)

Comment: Open up the JavaScript console in your browser. You will see an error. You are missing functions.

Comment: This code requires more javascript libraries. Looking at the page they are using alphabet.js, bubbles.js and jquery You are only including alphabet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/rmadhuram/he1pqyzz/1/

The trick was to add jQuery, then add the external library into the `<body>` of the HTML, like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess I should have gotten that. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Here's the final "base result" for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/d1yzrbqp/

Answer (score 1):

Try to put space between blue and red: `var letterColors = [blue, red];`

For me it was the only problem.